# Can I check reachability of HTTP server URL endpoint with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have iPad application written in Swift that communicates with our HTTP server through REST API and I need to add listener to two types of events: HTTP server application is down (502,503,504) and HTTP server application is on again (2xx, 3xx, 4xx).

Right now I'm using Alamofire's `NetworkReachabilityManager` through which I can set a listener to events like **network not reachable** and **network is reachable again**. I can even put there a host to our server through constructor invocation `NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.ourserver.com")` but it does not really do what I exactly want. It only finds out whether IP address to which the host routes is reachable (ping).

```
class NetworkReachabilitySubject {

    private let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.ourserver.com")
    private var observers : [NetworkReachabilityObserver] : []

    // MARK: - Methods

    func startListening() {
        manager?.listener = { status in
            for observer in self.observers {
                observer.networkStatusChanged(currentStatus: status)
            }
        }
        manager?.startListening()
    }

}
```

I need to go little further and manage when **server application** is down/on, not only when its **host** is down/on. For this purposes I created a special HTTP endpoint `http://www.ourserver.com/isalive` that can be used to resolve whether server application is down or not. Is there any way in Alamofire or other library to solve this problem? Ideally something like `HttpServerAppReachabilityManager(endpoint: "http://www.ourserver.com/isalive")` that does the same things as Alamofire's `NetworkReachabilityManager` but in addition it can also manage a reachability of that URL endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

With this tiny snippet you can check the HTTP status code:

```
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

 dataTask = 
    defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in 
    defer {
      self?.dataTask = nil
    }
    let httpResponsStatusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
    // Now check the status code
  }
  dataTask?.resume()
```